# What should be done to the users who post the same spam answers on every question they visited?

Tags: support, status-completed, flags, spam

I have observing these two users with the same name and posting exactly the same answer again and again on every question they answered. I have already raised flags to attention the moderators but still nothing happened that could stop them to posting the same answer.

Users:
1 - [brianfo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4570840/brianfo?tab=answers&sort=votes)
2 - [brianfo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4570777/brianfo)

Answers they are posting.

[image]
[image]

Both accounts are created today and still spamming on StackOverflow. What should be done in this kind of scenarios to stop them ?

Here is the custom flag that I have raised first:
[image]

Comment: Just flag as spam when you see them, they will be handled with eventually (as in this case).

Comment: They seem to have already been dealt with.

Comment: I already flags many of there answers but they keep posting the same answers. I have raised custom flags but still no response from the Moderator.

Comment: Yeah I think so. But I was raising from past 1 hour which forces me to ask a question here, how to handle this kind of situation.

Comment: @Joker: custom flags usually take some time to handle, up to 24 hours depending on the time you flag and the number of moderators on at the time. Last time I heard I think there was over 1000 custom flags in the backlog for moderators to handle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah I just killed those accounts, along with a third one. They were all coming from the same IP address, which is now completely blocked from posting so this particular spammer should no longer bother us (at least until they find a new IP address anyway).

I didn't see your custom flag earlier, because for some strange reason the UI that displays spam flags does not display any other flags that happen to have been raised on the same post. I have marked that flag helpful now. Thank you for your help bringing this to our attention.

Comment: yeah I raised a custom flag first which was active before I edited my question but now It is reviewed and marked as helpful by a moderator.

Comment: BoltClock the spammer is again on the StackOverflow. [brianfo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4570936/brianfo) is a new account with the same name.

Comment: @Joker: That didn't take very long at all.

Comment: Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers&search=brianfo; flagged a post. -- I'll re-run that search from time to time.

Comment: Sure. I'm in the tavern right now - I'll probably keep watch on this guy for the next few.

Comment: It will be a time consuming way for you. Is there is nothing else you can do something like checking if the username is brianfo and the answer is the same that It posts then auto delete it. ?

Comment: @Joker: It's possible to blacklist user input but I can't edit the blacklist.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - A better search is to look for "Long Path Tool" (and variants). They've been spamming this since at least 2010, with north of 100 accounts. They were calling themselves "trianfo" on Friday, and something else on Thursday. IP blocks hold them back for few months, then they find some other location to operate from. They're on one of my regular spam search lists.

Comment: @BradLarson: [already doing that](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3051022#3051022) :-)